# "Package could not be registered" when deploying Windows Phone 8.1 solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I am getting the error message quoted in the title when I try to deploy a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 solution to either the emulator on my PC or to a device. The error is not accompanied by any error codes, and I have no other hints as to exactly what the problem is, other than various tips that I have found online, both here and on other forums.

The background to this is that this is a corporate application which is already in use within my organisation. It was developed by an external supplier, and I have taken over the support internally. I have what I believe to be the current source code and Visual Studio solution for the project, and the company is registered as a developer on the Microsoft App portal. There are existing versions of the software on the portal, which is used to provide software updates to the devices which are in use.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with this solution (VS2017 does not seem to like it).

I have tried various suggestions that I have found online, including:

- Checking that the Publisher ID is correct
- Ensuring that I am logged into the correct developer account when trying to deploy the solution
- Ensuring that the Package.appxmanifest and WMAppManifest.xml files have consistent Product and Publisher IDs
- Ensuring that all of the images referenced by those two manifests have the correct paths and filenames
- Looking at the event logs suggested at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973484(v=vs.85).aspx (none of them have anything in them, and I have no error code to match against the table given there).

I am now at a loss. This seems to be a fairly common issue with deploying Windows Phone software, judging by the number of people online who seem to have experienced a similar problem. However, some of the issues/suggestions that I have found online are a few years old, and I don't know which are still relevant.

I have not done Windows Phone development since the introduction of the App Store, so I have no previous experience of this way of deploying software.

I would welcome any suggestions of how to proceed. Is there any way to determine the exact cause of a "package could not be registered" error, in the absence of an error code or any event log entries?

Comment: I have managed to find an answer to my own question. I had added an entry to the <Capabilities> section: <DeviceCapability Name="pointOfService"/> to the Package.appxmanifest, when I was having problems with the Windows.Devices.PointOfService namespace not being recognised. This turned out to be the source of the problem. I commented out that line from the appxmanifest, and the software deployed.

Comment: I have to say that the diagnostic information from the emulators and device stinks. Any sensible software would be able to tell me why it didn't like what I was trying to load onto the device. It wouldn't leave me guessing, with absolutely no clues whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to remove from Package.appxmanifest a line which I had added while investigating an earlier problem where the Windows.Devices.PointOfService namespace wasn't being recognised. I added a  line, following a recommendation that I saw among the suggestions I found while googling that problem. This turned out to be the source of the unhelpful "package could not be registered" message. Commenting out the line from Package.appxmanifest resulted in the software deploying to the emulator.

Comment: Update: Even though I can deploy the software to the emulator, it still does not deploy to an actual device. This time, the error says "Install failed. Please contact your software vendor." There is no error code of any kind, and there are no entries in the logs which supposedly should contain relevant events.

Comment: Further update: it deploys via the Windows Phone Application Deployment tool, even though deployment via Visual Studio fails.